# Django 1.11 to 2.0 => unit tests are 2x slower

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just upgraded from Django 1.11 to 2.0.
I changed nothing in the code except backwards incompatibilities:

- changing `url` to `path` with route instead of regex argument
- adding a few `on_delete` arguments where I had forgotten

Here are my unit tests run in local before and after the migration:

- before: `Ran 496 tests in 62.891s`
- after: `Ran 496 tests in 157.244s`

I have tested with my CI that runs on an Heroku environment (to be sure it's not related to my local env), same result (2x longer to execute tests).

**Question**

Do you have any idea of what's going on here? How would you debug this?

Comment: Good question!  I haven't seen any issues in my upgrades.  Maybe run a profiler over it and see.  Some ideas though:  Have you disabled migrations in test mode? Are you creating a lot of data in a base test class 'setup' method?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBacker. I don't think it's related to migrations, I can see the time to init DB is the same. Plus, I can see it's longer even out of the testing. I was thinking of a default parameter that could have changed in between.

Comment: Sorry David, not much I can say.  I've not experienced it, but I'm really curious to see what it is once you find out.  I get my 1k+ tests done in 169s, with many of them doing quite a bit of work :( I've upgrade from 1.11 to 2.1 (and now 2.2) without seeing a noticeable slowdown.

Comment: @AndrewBacker I posted an answer, it may interest you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on the Django Changelog [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.0/#django-contrib-auth)

> The default iteration count for the PBKDF2 password hasher is increased from 36,000 to 100,000.

As I'm creating lots of user in my unit tests, this change had a huge impact.

For the comparison, defining in settings.py this:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = ('django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',)
```

lead to 5x slower tests: `Ran 496 tests in 31.781s`

I guess the right solution to keep fast tests is to define a custom PASSWORD_HASHERS value when running tests.

Comment: Oh wow, forgot about that completely.  Its been set since 2014 in this project.  I had *no* idea it made *that* much of a difference!  Its mentioned in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/ as well, should be at the top of the page though.

Comment: One thing to try, if you aren't already, is creating all your standard test data in the `setUpTestData(cls):` method, then making references to it in `setUp` for convenience.   Dropped time quite a bit as well, not doing for every test case.